# How to add trigger for Lambda, with swagger and RestApi?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, aws-cloudformation

I'm trying to create Api gateway and lambda function with cloudformation. Current I'm able to create api gateway with swagger, and lambda function. The issue I have is the lambda function dont have the trigger with support to be api gateway. How to add trigger to this lambda function ?

#### the RestApi Definitation

```
MyRestApi:
 Properties:
  ApiKeySourceType: HEADER
  BodyS3Location:
    Bucket: bucketName
    Key: swagger.yaml
  Name: OmmaClaimsApi
Type: AWS::ApiGateway::RestApi
```

#### The Function Definitation

```
MyLambda:
 Properties:
  Code:
    S3Bucket: bucketName
    S3Key: lambda.zip
  FunctionName: MyLambda
  Handler: index.handler
  MemorySize: 512
  Role: !GetAtt 'LambdaExecutionRole.Arn'
  Runtime: nodejs8.10
  Timeout: 300
Type: AWS::Lambda::Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Your lambda should go through the API gateway through proxy integration:

`/{proxy+}`

In your serverless yaml, try to add something like:

```
functions:
  post-transaction:
    handler: your.lambda.LambdaHandler
    events:
      - http:
          path: /{proxy+}
          method: any
```